# Handling Parameters With Space Within Bash Script

Tags: bash, parameters, whitespace, quoting

I got the following script:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
FNAME="FILE NAME"
cat ${FNAME}"
```

and a file

```
$ ls  FILE\ NAME 
FILE NAME
```

and no clue how to quote. Running -x gives

```
+ FNAME='FILE NAME'
+ cat FILE NAME
cat: FILE: No such file or directory
cat: NAME: No such file or directory
```

This is a testcase for running openssl with -subj containing spaces in a bash script.

There is a solution, but I can't see it.

Kind Regards
Maniac

Comment: `cat "$FNAME"` does it for me.

Answer (score 0):

... does it for me too... THX!

Was sending '-subj /C=DE/ST=.../CN=dummy.domain' to openssl, which is treated as *one* parameter not as two as expected.
My fault.